Arc on an ellipsewith defined angle
I have trouble understanding the arc command.
I have the following drawing, the angle (grey lines) are 5 degrees, resp. 175 degrees.
The ellipse is highly eccentric approx 1:9.
I need to draw the red sector around the centerpoint, which is 190 degrees.
My thinking was to first calculate the position of the startpoint, move there then arc with begin angle=175, delta angle=190, x radius=9, y-radius=1.
(Actually I have a negative delta angle, and started at the "wrong side", but would have expected it not to make a difference...

The result is correctly centered, and follows the correct ellipse. However, the path seems to start and stop much closer to the 0 degrees resp. 180 degrees.
\documentclass{standalone}      
\usepackage{xcolor, tikz}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0cm,0cm) rectangle (33.8667cm,19.0500cm);
\definecolor{11516E}{HTML}{11516E}
\definecolor{000000}{HTML}{000000}
  \path[draw,inner sep=0pt,Triangle-,line width=1.5,color=000000,solid] ++(11.2cm, 13.8158cm) +(9.5482cm, -0.0173cm)  arc [start angle=5.0, delta angle=-190.0, x radius=9.0cm, y radius=1.0cm] ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Welcome. This is not how ellipses work. The calculation for a point on the ellipse is (cos(angle)*xradius, sin(angle)*yradius) or (angle:xradius and yradius) in the polar coordinate specification that can be used by TikZ. This makes the angle to that point actually atan(tan(angle)*yradius/xradius), if my keyboard math is correct. Also, you will need the bending library loaded to have the arrow tip not distort the path.

This ought to be a duplicate: Q705960. In short: calculate the angle, clip it or let PGF/TikZ find the point (via intersections/spath3).

@Qrrbrbirlbel : I will try your calculation today, If it works I would like to accept your answer, that is something I would have never come up with!
